# XMPP - Sign up a new user

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm working with Openfire and XMPP. My problem is: whenever I want to sign someone up I need to log into Openfire, like this.

```
connection.login(Username, Password);
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
            accountManager.createAccount(Username1, Password1);
```

So, how can I avoid this useless login?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split login functionality from createAccount().

You must connect on Openfire server (without provide user and password), then ask for createAccount

```
    //...connection builder
    connection.connect(); 
 AccountManager.getInstance(connection).sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
            username = username.toLowerCase();

                Map<String,String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                attributes.put("name", fullName);
                attributes.put("email", email);
        AccountManager.getInstance(connection).createAccount(username, password, attributes);
//now you can do connection.login(username,password)
```